# Bootstrap- How to align select and textbox horizontally on one row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align to align the select box and textbox horizontally on one line. I tried using inline on css, but it's not working.

```
<div class="control-group span6">

<label for="trp_code">Transporter: </label>

<select class="form-control" name="trp_code" id="trp_code" title="Transporter" style="width: 350px;">

</select>



<label for="lrno">LR No: </label>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="lrno" name ="lrno" size='10' style="width:100px;" onblur ="notempty(this.value)">

<label for="lrdate">LR Date: </label>

<input type="text" class="form-control"  name ="lrdate" id="lrdate" style="width:100px;" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" class="calendar" title="LR Date">

</div></td>
```

Comment: refer this https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_inline&stacked=h

Answer (score 0):

you can use Bootstrap Grid Systems in order to align the Select and TextBox in a single line.
Refer the Link https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Answer (score 0):

How about this code :

```
<div class="control-group span6 container row">
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="trp_code" class="control-label">Transporter: </label>
            <select class="form-control" name="trp_code" id="trp_code" title="Transporter" style="width: 350px;"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="lrno" class="control-label">LR No: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lrno" name="lrno" size='10' style="width:100px;" onblur="notempty(this.value)">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="lrdate" class="control-label">LR Date: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lrdate" id="lrdate" style="width:100px;" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can work on this..

Answer (score -1):

For this you can use `Bootstrap Inline form`. for detailed information [click here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline)